# Generate table of all databases and schema with a single psql command

Tags: postgresql, schema

In PostgreSQL is it possible to generate a list of all databases and all schema with a single psql command?

To be concrete, let me provide an example.

I have two databases in a PotgreSQL database cluster: `accounts` and `people`. In the `accounts` database there are these schema  (beyond the default): `hr` and `finance`. In the `people` database there are these schema (beyond the default): `hr`, `admin`, `backup`.

Is there a single psql command I can run that generates results something like this:

```
database | schema
-----------------
accounts |  hr
accounts |  finance
people   |  hr
people   |  admin
people   |  backup
```

Or is the only way to generate this information to connect multiple times and run separate queries?

Answer (score 1):

> In PostgreSQL is it possible to generate a list of all databases and
>   all schema with a single psql command?

No. The list of schemas of a database is private to that database and cannot be obtained without being connected to it.
The list of databases is available with `\l` or `select * from pg_database`.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Vérité noted that

> The list of schemas of a database is private to that database...

One can see this by looking at the documentation for [System Catalogs, Overview](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs-overview.html) page which says, in part,

> Most system catalogs are copied from the template database during
>   database creation and are thereafter database-specific. A few catalogs
>   are physically shared across all databases in a cluster; these are
>   noted in the descriptions of the individual catalogs.

Looking at the [`pg_namespace` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-namespace.html) it is clear that `pg_namespace` is not shared. (For an example that *is* shared, see [`pg_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-database.html)).